# Python Matplotlib error when using matplotlib.axis.XAxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the Enthought IDE for Python, and I'm plotting a matrix named recmat using matshow. Matshow plots the xlabes on top of the plot, I'd like them to be on the bottom. The code below leads to this error message:

TypeError: set_ticks_position() missing 1 required positional argument: 'position'

```
plt.matshow(recmat)
matplotlib.axis.XAxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

How can I fix this? Or is there another way to move the labels? 
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `xaxis.tick_bottom()` for the current axes as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

recmat = np.random.random((100,100))
plt.matshow(recmat)

ax = plt.gca()
plt.colorbar()
ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()

plt.show()
```